# What is a core object in a DOM?

Tags: dom

This question was asked in a java quiz. It was an MCQ which had following four options:

- Data
- Event
- Node
- None of these

I don't have much experience with DOM and after searching for it I was still unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM is the "Document Object Model", and models an in-memory tree of nodes.  You can find the DOM api easily -- it's part of core java.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html

You'll see that Node is the only item listed from their options.

Event is part of SAX parsing which can be used to build a DOM.  Data (as Value or Attribute) are properties of a Node.